# TimeSpan Conversion Fails

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008

In my TimeIn.aspx File, I am displaying clock with following code:

```
<div>
    <div>
        <asp:ScriptManager runat="server" ID="ScriptManager1" />
        <br />

        <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="UpdatePanel1">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="Label4" Text="Current Time: "/>
                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="Label2" />
            </ContentTemplate>
            <Triggers>
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Timer1" EventName="Tick" />
            </Triggers>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
        <asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" OnTick="Timer1_Tick" Interval="1000" />
    </div>
    <br />

    <br />
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Check In" OnClick="CheckIn" />
</div>
```

The clock works fine. Then in TimeIn.aspx.cs file, I have written CheckIn method:

```
protected void CheckIn(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TimeSpan currtime = TimeSpan.Parse(Label2.Text);
    int eid = Convert.ToInt32(Session["EID"]);
    DBClient = new DBConnection();
    DBClient.CheckIn(eid, currtime, DateTime.Now.Date.ToString());
    Response.Redirect("ECheckin.aspx");
}
```

In Database, the Datatype of `CheckinTime` column is `Time(7)`.
When CheckIn event fires it gives exception on first line of TimeSpan.Parse because Label2.Text have time with time format added (AM/PM). 
Sample value of Label2.Text is: `1:41:28 PM`
Whats the best solution to deal with this situation? I really want to use `Time` datatype in sql server because later i will have to perform calculations on time field.

Comment: Put value of label2.Text/Database in question.

Comment: `In Database, the Datatype of CheckinTime column is Time(7).`. Means??

Comment: @Nikhil Agrawal I am using Sql Server 2008 as backend DB. In my application DB Table, there is a column of CheckinTime whose datatype is Time(7). I want to store Checkin time in that field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Timespan is basically difference between two times.

Or we can say a stopwatch where value in stopwatch is time that have elapsed since when clock started and when clock stopped.

It has nothing to do with AM or PM.

```
Timespan = Date1 - Date2
```

I guess the error that you are getting will be [FormatException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.formatexception)

Your format of Label Text is `DateTime` that's why AM/PM.

Instead of Timespan try using `DateTime` instance

like

```
DateTime currtime = DateTime.Parse(Label2.Text);
```

Comment: I doubt your statement "Timespan is basically difference between two times". Timespan is a struct which represents a time interval ... that's it. Your statement leads to the perception that timespan can only hold the difference which I think is wrong.

Comment: Your comment supports me not contradicts me. You said `Timespan is a struct which represents a time interval`. That's what I said. Interval is difference only. I chose Difference. You chose Interval. One and the same thing. The name is Time Span meaning span between two times.

Comment: @Nikhil Agrawal Your code also works but I solved it by converting time to 24 hours format before storing in DB like: `string d = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:m:s"); TimeSpan currtime = TimeSpan.Parse(d);` thanks

Comment: @NidaSulheri: See what you did is what i said in my answer. Remove AM PM. You did that by converting it to 24 hour format. And as you said it worked fine. Nice to help you. Chao.

Answer (score 0):

you can do adding timespan to datetime like below

```
  TimeSpan timespan = new TimeSpan(03,00,00);
    DateTime time = DateTime.Today.Add(timespan);
    string displayTime = time.ToString("hh:mm tt");
```

instead of 03,00,00 you can directly pass your timespan variable